# How to check the datatype of a property in an entity in a T4 template file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, templates, entity, t4

I am customizing my .tt file in EF 4.0. Now as part f customization I need to add some code to a property in POCO class generation, if the property type is `Nullable<System.DateTime>` or `System.DateTime`. I am not able to find the proper syntax for comparison.

I have the following code in .tt file.

```
foreach (EdmProperty edmProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity))
{
bool isDefaultValueDefinedInModel = (edmProperty.DefaultValue != null);
//Here I need to check whether my edmProperty is Nullable<System.DateTime> or System.DateTime, so that I can insert custom code.
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  if (((PrimitiveType)edmProperty.TypeUsage.EdmType).
        PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime && edmProperty.Nullable)
```

Answer (score -2):

Regular check:

```
if(edmproperty.GetType() == typeof(System.DateTime)){ }
```

Nullable check:

```
if(edmproperty != null && edmproperty.GetType() == typeof(Nullable<System.DateTime>))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i solved it in a different way. Following is the code. if (((PrimitiveType)edmProperty.TypeUsage.EdmType).PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime && edmProperty.Nullable)
  {

Comment: `edmproperty.GetType()` will always return a `typeof(EdmProperty)`, never a `DateTime` or a `Nullable<T>`.